# Need XSLT to Transform XML of one form to another

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT . I need an XSLT to transform my XML of one form to another. Below are the input & Output

**INPUT**

```
<AssetDataCollection>
<!-- Asset Data will be repeated for each service tag -->
<AssetData>
  <REF_ID_LIST>
    <REF_ID NAME="MANUFACTUREDATE" VALUE="05/03/2013" />
    <REF_ID NAME="REGION" VALUE="DAO" />
    <REF_ID NAME="EMBMAC1" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
    <REF_ID NAME="EMBMAC2" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
    <REF_ID NAME="EMBMAC3" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
    <REF_ID NAME="AC1" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
    <REF_ID NAME="MAC2" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
    <REF_ID NAME="MAC3" VALUE="D4BED9403E24" />
  </REF_ID_LIST>
</AssetData>
</AssetDataCollection>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<AssetDataCollection>
<!-- Asset Data will be repeated for each service tag -->
<AssetData>
<MANUFACTUREDATE>05/03/2013</MANUFACTUREDATE>
<REGION>DAO</REGION>
<EMBMAC1>D4BED9403E24</EMBMAC1>
<EMBMAC2>D4BED9403E24</EMBMAC2>
<EMBMAC3>D4BED9403E24</EMBMAC3>
<AC1>D4BED9403E24</AC1>
<MAC2>D4BED9403E24</MAC2>
<MAC3>D4BED9403E24</MAC3>
</AssetData>
</AssetDataCollection>
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/AssetDatCollection/AssetData/REF_ID_LIST/REF_ID"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="REF_ID">
<xsl:variable name="newnam" select=" REF_ID[@NAME]"/>
<xsl:variable name=”newval” select=” REF_ID[@VALUE]”/>
<xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$newnam/@NAME"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select=” REF_ID[@VALUE]”/> <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:text>/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$newnam/@NAME"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Tried in http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html, I was not getting the correct output.

Comment: Can you provide us what you tried so far ?

Comment: Can not ask what you've tried hence you done it.

Comment: of one form to another means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use three templates, the first one is the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the second one makes sure the `REF_ID_LIST` just processes its children

```
<xsl:template match="REF_ID_LIST">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the third one transforms the `REF_ID` elements by doing

```
<xsl:template match="REF_ID">
  <xsl:element name="{@NAME}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: *fully formatted answer* `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AssetDataCollection\AssetData\REF_ID_LIST">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="REF_ID">
  <xsl:element name="{@NAME}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE"/>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`